# Set the file permission to -rwx------

Tags: permissions, chmod

**My goal** is to set the permission of a file to `-rwx------`. The file currently has the permission `-rwxr-xr-x`. I have set this with `chmod +rwx`.

Comment: Try `chmod 700 ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chmod` is the right tool to use, and `chmod 700` should accomplish the task.
For a lot more info, check out [this guide](https://linuxize.com/post/chmod-command-in-linux/).

Comment: Thank you! It was helpful and i was able to set the right permission with your suggested command.